# Level curves to two functions for solving nonlinear system of equations

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to solve a system of nonlinear equations:

x^2 + y*sin(y) - 3 = 0 x*y + exp(x) + y -5 = 0

So I introduced the two functions f1 = x^2 + y*sin(y) - 3 and f2 = x*y + exp(x) + y -5. Now I am trying to plot the level curves(at 0) so I can see how many solutions exists. But I am unable to plot a meaningful result(i.e finding the intersections).

Code

```
x=linspace(-15,15,400);

y=linspace(-15,15,400);

f=@(x,y)(x.^2+y.*sin(y)-3);

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

Z=f(X,Y);

contour(X,Y,Z,10)

hold on

f=@(x,y)(x*y+exp(x)+y-5);

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

Z=f(X,Y);

contour(X,Y,Z,100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems with what you do I believe:

1. You're forgetting to use the dot product in the formula: `f=@(x,y)(x*y+exp(x)+y-5)`, it should be: `f=@(x,y)(x.*y+exp(x)+y-5)`, because you use it on matrices X and Y. This already gives correct results for that function.
2. You use contour which plots a 2D contour plot of a surface, which is not what you'd want to use to see zeros of 2D functions. -> Instead use `surf`
3. You plot `x*y+exp(x)+y-5` until 15 in dimension `x`, which is already in the order of magnitude of `1e6`..., so of course, you don't see the places it crosses zero very precisely any more...

Try this code:

```
x=linspace(-15,5,30);
y=linspace(-15,15,30);
f=@(x,y)(x.^2+y.*sin(y)-3);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=f(X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
hold on
f=@(x,y)(x.*y+exp(x)+y-5);
Z=f(X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

It's not incredibly clear to see where they become zero, but it's a start...

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you directly use `solve` function?

```
syms x y
[sol_x, sol_y]=solve(x^2 + y*sin(y) - 3 == 0, x*y + exp(x) + y -5 == 0,x,y)
```

Comment: That is easier, yes. But I want to plot the level curves (at 0) to check how many solutions exists and then invoke my numerical method to solve for them.

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

    `ezplot('x^2 + y*sin(y) - 3',[-10 10 -10 10]);
    hold on;
    ezplot('x*y + exp(x) + y -5',[-10 10 -10 10]);`